# Sum is returning some vague values. All I want to do is get Sum of Elements in my Mutable Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, literals

& yes I did google "How to get sum of array elements" but I want to know what's going on wrong here? If I use break points and see after execution of this line "sum = sum + (int) A[i];" sum has some vague values.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end
@implementation MyClass
@end

int solution(NSMutableArray *A) 
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <A.count; i ++)
  {
    NSLog(@"A.count: %ld", A.count);
    sum = sum + (int) A[i];   //A[i] has to return a value right?**strong text** 
  }
   NSLog(@"The final sum is: %d", sum);
   return sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
@autoreleasepool 
{
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"3",@"1",@"2",@"4",@"3", nil];
    solution(A);        
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do a log of the element within `A[i]` to see if it prints anything.

Comment: I did, it is also getting the same value as sum. Sorry, I thought I should remove the NSLog statements.

Comment: What do you mean by "some vague values"?

Comment: @m69 not sure, they are some random 4 digit numbers(mostly pointer values). The answer below does help solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements within your array are `NSString` objects. You should use `NSNumber` objects:

```
NSMutableArray *A = [@[@3,@1,@2,@4,@3] mutableCopy];
```

Also, you can't just cast them as ints. To get an `int` from an `NSNumber` you would need to call call `[A[i] intValue]`. Otherwise you will be summing the *pointer* values.

```
 sum = sum + [A[i] intValue];
```

Comment: @skypirate you could use this dude's solution.

Comment: Yeah what @johnpatrickmorgan said does makes sense. Although I have to type cast it to int get rid of compiler warning, hence "sum = sum + (int)[A[i] integerValue];" looks like the complete solution. I think that solves my problem, Thank you guys.

Comment: With an `array` of `NSNumbers`, you can just use the `@sum` collection operator instead of a loop.  `int sum = [[A valueForKeyPath:@"sum"] intValue];`

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the values of the string instead of the integer values.
Simply replace

```
sum = sum + (int) A[i];
```

with the following

```
sum = sum +  [A[i] integerValue];
```

Comment: Hey @BenAvery, doing this leaves me a complier warning "Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'" hence I have to type cast it to int. Hence will "sum = sum + (int)[A[i] integerValue];" be the correct solution? Thanks for help.

Comment: you can use [A[i] intValue] if you are converting to an Int sorry.